# Load spring logback.xml from s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

So, what I want is to put my logback.xml in the aws s3 bucket and when my service is deployed in ECS of aws, the logback.xml should be picked from s3 bucket.

Similarly, when we want the logback.xml file to be picked from outside the root repository in local  machine we use

```
logging.config= path to logback.xml
```

Let me know if we can do that and how?

I tried adding env variable as

```
logging.config = s3bucket file URL/arn/object URL
```

it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Spring will take that S3 URL and automatically know how to connect to an S3 bucket and perform S3 object operations to load the file from there. You will need to add something to your docker image's startup script to download that file from S3 to the local file system, probably using the [AWS CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html), before starting the Spring application.